# MiniProfiler MVC DBContext - Unable to determine the provider name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to use mini profiler to profile ef database actions but i can seem to get it to work.

I've got:

```
public partial class BuzzEntities : DbContext
{
    public BuzzEntities() : 
        base(GetProfiledConnection(), true) 
    { 
    } 

    private static DbConnection GetProfiledConnection() 
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BuzzEntities"].ConnectionString;
        var connection = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection(connectionString); 
        return new EFProfiledDbConnection(connection, MiniProfiler.Current); 
    }
}
```

Then I use a unit of work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;
    private BuzzEntities context = new BuzzEntities();
}
```

But when i get this error:

Unable to determine the provider name for connection of type 'StackExchange.Profiling.Data.EFProfiledDbConnection'

I've got

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" />
      <add name="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" invariant="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" description="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProvider" type="MvcMiniProfiler.Data.ProfiledDbProviderFactory, MvcMiniProfiler.EntityFramework, Version=1.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b44f9351044011a3" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

in my web.config

Answer (score 0):

The EF6 nuget has been published. It is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF6/) and can be installed using `Install-Package MiniProfiler.EF6 -Pre`

To initialize, simply call the following in your application startup logic:

```
using StackExchange.Profiling.EntityFramework6;

...

protected void Application_Start()
{
    MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
}
```

Be sure to call this before using EF in any way.

If you need to hook up EF5 or earlier, use the [EF5 Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler.EF5), and follow the instructions on [MiniProfiler.com](http://MiniProfiler.com) to hook it up.